# Can you view the history of what was printed out to the console in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Need to get a datetime string I printed out with datetime.now() a few days ago. Is there a file anywhere where this is stored?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no (or maybe fortunately, as it could grow in a massive unwanted file fairly quickly).

Python has excellent logging facility though. Look at the module `logging`. It is very easy to use. It is very good practice to replace your usual print statements by `logging.debug`, `logging.info` or whatever.

Using things like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=my_filename,
                    format='%(message)s (%(asctime)-15s)',
                    level=level)
console = logging.StreamHandler()
logging.getLogger().addHandler(console)
```

you can have the output be printed on your console, but also saved in a file.